# como fazer update com coluna com aspas simples sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

Estou precisando fazer update em uma coluna que tem monte de aspas simples no campo, foi inserido conteudo com o ckeditor entao tem varias tags do tipo

```
<span style="FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-FAMILY: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; mso-fareast-font-family: 'Times New Roman'; mso-ansi-language: PT-BR; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR; mso-bidi-language: AR-SA"><font face="Arial" size="2">meu conteudo </font></span>
```

O problema esta em aspa simples times aspa simples' / `'Times New Roman';`

quando rodo essa consulta no sql manager seria pra substiiuir as aspas simples por aspas duplas.

Quando coloco [aspas aspas e mais uma no meio] ele já da erro!!, a tag já fica sublinhado o `sql` pensa que e comentário depois da segunda aspa o restante da string fica cinza!
Já tentei por aspas duplas e simples no meio também não deu certo.

Essa atualização que preciso.

```
UPDATE pessoas SET nome = replace(nome, ''', '"') WHERE nome LIKE '%'%';
```

Alguém sabe como resolvo isso?

Answer (score 3):

No Sql-Server você "escapa" as aspas simples duplicando ela.

Então a solução seria assim:

```
UPDATE pessoas SET nome = replace(nome, '''', '"') WHERE nome LIKE '%''%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer uso do Caractere de Escape.

Ele é um termo para identificar um caractere único, dentro de uma cadeia que altera o significado do seu sucessor.

Podemos colocar como exemplo a quebra de linha em arquivos de texto "n" é um caractere comum como qualquer outro porém quando adicionado o \n seu significado muda "em programação". \n em uma string é a quebra de linha.

> Resolvendo o problema...

'->'(essa aspa altera o resultado de seu sucessor que também é uma aspa)', então quando você coloca uma barra antes dela você altera o resultado do sucessor dela.

ou seja para não ocorrer problemas, você só precisaria adicionar um caractere de escape antes dela, no caso do SQL Server e em muitas linguagens de programação é a "\", nunca vi outro sem ser esse.

> Exemplo com caractere de escape ' **\'** ', aplicando no seu caso ficaria assim `UPDATE pessoas SET nome = replace(nome, '\'', '"') WHERE nome LIKE '%\'%';`

Answer (score 0):

Mantenha as aspas simples amigo, faça um replace para a aspas dupla com [escape](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caractere_de_escape) na simples assim você não vai ter problema na Sintaxe do SQL-Server.

> Exemplo

```
UPDATE pessoas SET nome = replace(nome, '\'', '"') WHERE nome LIKE '%\'%';
```

Mas no seu caso vai dar problema em seu HTML. Porque o `'Times New Roman';` está dentro do atributo `style` então no final vai ficar `... style="font-family: "Times New Roman";"`